# python ctypes cdll.LoadLibrary() fails after certain number of dll loads - WindowsError: [1114]

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

i'am loading DLLs created by a third party program using ctypes in python 2.7 win8.1 64bit. The code works fine for ~150 loads. This little loop is where i load the DLLS:

```
for i in os.listdir(self.path):
            if '.dll' in i:
                self.DLL = cdll.LoadLibrary(self.path+'//'+i)
```

and fails with the following error msg:

```
   self.DLL = cdll.LoadLibrary(self.path+'//'+i)
  File "C:\Users\Johannes\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 444, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Johannes\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
```

I changed the order of the DLLs so its definetly not a certain DLL that fails but the ~150th DLL that fails. Is there any limit on loading DLLs?? I cant imagine that's the cause, but also have no idea what i'am doing wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: How big are the dlls? You might be running out of memory . . .

Comment: they are about 350KB each. I've 16GB of ram so i should be fine there i hope. Also i should see my memory usage in the task manager when i run my script? The memory usage displayed by the tskmgr is only changing by a couple percent

Comment: In my test on Windows 7, the first limit I hit is 128 slots for fiber local storage (FLS). After that, [`FlsAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `FLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES`. Each DLL that statically links the CRT allocates an FLS index for storing per-thread data. If this fails, then `__DllMainCRTStartup` returns `FALSE`, and thus `ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED`.

Comment: If this is case for you, then after the failed load, check `windll.kernel32.FlsAlloc(None)`. It should return -1 (or unsigned 4294967295).

Comment: As a workaround, just free libraries that you no longer need. When detaching the CRT calls `FlsFree`, so its current FLS index will become available for another DLL. The `_ctypes` extension module has `FreeLibrary`, so for example just call `_ctypes.FreeLibrary(DLL._handle)`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks that seems to be the cause of the problem. But now iam running into a bigger problem - i need all the DLLs loaded because i'am running a realtime simulation and loading each DLL just before i need to call it is to time consuming (need to load a big txt file associated with each DLL as well). You said _Each DLL that statically links the CRT allocates an FLS index for storing per-thread data._ So if i load the DLLs into another thread that might work? And if so do you have any idea / example how to do that? Thanks

Comment: No, loading in another thread/fiber won't work. Each CRT needs a specific index in the per-fiber FLS array. Every fiber/thread created in the process will notify the CRT's `__DllMainCRTStartup` with a `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`, at which time it allocates a `_tiddata` struct for per-thread / per-fiber data (e.g. for `errno`) and stores the struct's address in its allotted FLS slot.

Comment: Can you possibly rebuild these DLLs to link dynamically to a single CRT instead of statically to a private CRT? Otherwise you'll have to find a way to juggle the DLLs, loading and freeing as needed.